# ¿Como saber si ya existe un archivo para no sobre escribirlo?

Tags: php

soy principiante, lo que estoy haciendo es un formulario que se guarde en un documento .txt, el problema es que cuando se guarda no se sabe si ya existe con ese nombre o no y si pones el mismo nombre se escribe encima del que ya existía, si me pueden ayudar por favor.

```
<?php
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $hora = $_POST["hora"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
    $producto = $_POST["producto"];
    $pt = $_POST["pt"];

    $Contenido = "
    VULKA ELEFANTE | VENTAS

    Folio: $folio
    Fecha: $fecha
    Hora: $hora
    ------------------------------
    Nombre: $nombre
    Apellido: $apellido
    ------------------------------
    Servico o Producto: $producto
    Precio Total: $pt
    ";

    $nombre_fichero = 'ventas/$folio.txt';

    if (file_exists($nombre_fichero)) {
        echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero ya existe - Favor de introducir un nuevo numero de folio.";
    } else {
        echo "El fichero $nombre_fichero no existe";
        $archivo=fopen("Ventas/N° Folio $folio.txt", "w");
        fwrite($archivo,$Contenido);
    }

header('Location: ventas.php');

?>
```

Comment: Muy buenas Ricardo, ¿el problema es que la función `file_exists` no te da el resultado esperado?

Comment: @Ricardo  puedes agregar el error que te muestra php?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si alguna de estas respuesta ha aclarado tu duda o de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 3):

El error lo tienes en la línea:

```
 $nombre_fichero = 'ventas/$folio.txt';
```

Tienes dos opciones para incluir una variable en un string de PHP:

- usar comillas dobles

> $nombre_fichero = "ventas/$folio.txt";

- concatenar

> $nombre_fichero = 'ventas/'.$folio.'.txt';

Para buscar ficheros a mí me gusta más la función `glob()`, pues me permite utilizar comodines: `*`, `?` y todas sus combinaciones. Sería algo así:

```
if (glob($nombre_fichero))
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar el mismo nombre de archivo para comprobar que existe y para guardarlo.

```
$nombre_fichero = 'ventas/$folio.txt';
```

```
$archivo=fopen("Ventas/N° Folio $folio.txt", "w");
```

Ten en cuenta que es sensible a las mayúsculas

Además, debes cerrar el archivo al abrirlo con fclose.